# watir ruby follow final url in the new window

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want to follow the new window url on click
like I have have link somesite .com/osijejf
so watir clicks on it and new window opens like next code

```
<a href="some url" target="blank">
```

So I want to see the final destination url of that window

hier is what I did till now:

```
b.frame(:id => 'main').link(:index => 0).click
url_after_click = b.url
```

So I have url but not the url in the new window.
With the goto I can go to the current window, but I want to see what happens in the new window and retrieve final url

If some can help me on this? tnx

Comment: Is there a redirect involved?  What are you actually trying to test?  Would it suffice to grab the HREF of the link you're clicking on?

Comment: Yes redericting is there in the new window so how to track the url of new window. I want to follow href, so not very ussefull to retrive it. Thats why i want to follow url in the new window

Comment: Again, what are you testing?  Unless your site has a range of links out of your control, you're verifying _something_, not just trying to find out what the user did with a script that user won't actually be running.  What is your end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know any details of the window and you just opened the windows, you could try using the last window in the `windows` collection. (From my experience, the windows collection appears to always be in the order that the windows were opened.)

You can get the last window using:

```
browser.windows.last
```

So you can get the url with:

```
browser.windows.last.use do
  puts browser.url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem, but I think you want to get URL of a new window that opens after you click a link.

To do that, you have to switch to the new window.

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.url
end
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-popups/

Comment: But i dont know the title and i want to use the one that is clicked on

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. What do you know about the new browser window?